# Visual Studio Code debugging the default ASP.NET Core MVC WebApp: does not work

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am using Manjaro linux and tried to debug the default ASP.NET Core MVC project but the debugging stopped without any error

I created the project with: `dotnet new mvc` in a `Meow` folder, nothing special, and then added a new configuration `.NET Core Launch (web)`.

It turns out that there is only a call to `dotnet build` defined in the `build` task in `tasks.json` as defined in `preLaunchTask` of the `launch.json` and that's it the debugging process starts and stops without showing any error.

When running `dotnet run`, everything works, so I am suspecting the issue comes more from my Visual Studio debug configuration.

In terminal tab I have:

```
> Executing task: dotnet build /home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow/Meow.csproj <

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20.63311 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 86.18 ms for /home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow/Meow.csproj.
  Meow -> /home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Meow.dll
  Meow -> /home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Meow.Views.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.62

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

The two files below that have been auto generated look fine.

`launch.json`

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Meow.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ,]
}
```

`tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Meow.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Update 1]

Tried to uninstall omnisharp and reinstall it (with a VSCode reboot in between):

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 2/3/2019, 11:19:16 AM
    Target: /home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow

OmniSharp server started with Mono 5.16.0.
    Path: /home/perret/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 21990

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on manjaro 0.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Mono 15.0 - "/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin"
            2: StandAlone 15.0 - "/home/perret/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Mono 15.0 - "/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin"
            CscToolPath = /home/perret/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1/.omnisharp/1.32.8/omnisharp/msbuild/15.0/Bin/Roslyn
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '/home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Project system 'OmniSharp.DotNet.DotNetProjectSystem' is disabled in the configuration.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in '/home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow/Meow.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpWorkspaceOptionsProvider
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow' on host 21903.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow/Meow.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file '/home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow/Meow.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project '/home/perret/Desktop/Playground/CSharpmusement/Meow/Meow.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Meow
```

[Update 2]

The debugger is installed properly (I tried a brand new fresh installed):

```
Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: linux, x86_64, name=manjaro, version=unknown

Downloading package 'OmniSharp for Linux (x64)' (30903 KB).................... Done!
Installing package 'OmniSharp for Linux (x64)'

Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (linux / x64)' (59407 KB).................... Done!
Installing package '.NET Core Debugger (linux / x64)'

Downloading package 'Razor Language Server (Linux / x64)' (44979 KB).................... Done!
Installing package 'Razor Language Server (Linux / x64)'

Finished
```

[Also filed an issue on Github](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2837).

Comment: Are you sure C# extension has installed .NET Core debugger properly?

Comment: @LexLi I think so (the Omnisharp tab does not show any error when starting and checking the project). Also it seems that debugging a simple console app is also stopping for no reason whatsoever.

Comment: Reinstall the extension and it should try to download the debugger again. Make sure the network allows external download.

Comment: @LexLi I updated my post, showing the Omnisharp log. The debugger was already setup.

Comment: @LexLi side note: `ctrl + shift + p`  and then there is a command to force downloading: "Debug: Download .NET Core Debugger" (just to point out that there is not necessarily a need to reinstall omnisharp to force it).

Comment: @LexLi will probably file an issue on the omnisharp-vscode Github, seen quite a few folks facing issues with Manjaro

Comment: .NET Core is only supported on certain Linux distributions, https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/linux-prereqs.md So in your case, the ultimate cause is that you are on a non-supported distribution.

Comment: @LexLi the .NET Core works just fine with Arch / Manjaro but the debugger is another beast, will this check this out: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Installing-the-.NET-Core-Debugger-on-Arch-Linu

Comment: The Microsoft .NET Core debugger is not open sourced, and it should have very limited support on Linux distributions. I don't think OmniSharp guys can help on such, but you might see what they say.

Comment: @LexLi you're right, just trying on Ubuntu and everything works like a charm out of the box... might be due to the libraries requirements, I keep investigating.

Comment: @LexLi managed to make it work in a voodoo fashion, will answer my question.

Comment: @LexLi fixed, works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question on those GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2604#issuecomment-460593882
- https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2837

Basically steps of my solution on a fresh Manjaro Gnome variant live session:

- Install ~~`yay` to enjoy AUR without struggling with the command line: `sudo pacman -Sy yay`~~ `yay -S dotnet-sdk mono binutils msbuild-stable visual-studio-code-bin --noconfirm` (see the [UPDATE] below).
- Setup everything you need (aka the .NET Core SDK, Mono, MSBuild and Visual Studio Code Insiders): `yay -S dotnet-sdk mono binutils msbuild-stable visual-studio-code-insiders --noconfirm`

  - Note: `binutils` cause the Gnome variant does not seem to embed that one natively, and this require for stripping in one of the steps of the `msbuild-stable` installation.
- Add the required environment variables that you would like to export at the end of your `.bashrc` file in your home folder:

  - `export MSBuildSDKsPath=/opt/dotnet/sdk/$(dotnet --version)/Sdks`
  - `export PATH="$PATH:/home/manjaro/.dotnet/tools"`
- Create a dummy project: `dotnet new mvc`
- Start Visual Studio Code Insiders: `code-insiders .`
- Install the C# extension
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
  `ext install ms-vscode.csharp`
- Download the .NET Code Debugger for the C# extension (if needed / not already done the first time)
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
  `Debug: Download .NET Core Debugger`
- Generate the `launch.json` and `tasks.json` files (if not already answered yes to the popup shows: "Would you like to add the required assets to build and debug your project?")
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
  `.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug`
- Install the tools for the development self-signed certificate
  `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dev-certs`
- Register the development self-signed certificate:
  `dotnet dev-certs https`
- Debugging (`.NET Core Launch (web)`)
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
  <kbd>F5</kbd>

This is not stable though, as pointed by one of the comments in my initial post, Arch / Manjaro are not officially supported by the debugger, but I found that this is more related to the version of Visual Studio Code, atm it only worked with the insiders edition for some reasons I completely ignore.

I will keep this answer updated whenever I will notice that I will no longer need to resort to the Insiders Edition.

---

**[UPDATE]**
[The official Visual Code AUR page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Visual_Studio_Code) shows the different versions available:

> The following packages provide VSCode:
>
> - code (open-source release)
> - visual-studio-code-bin AUR (Microsoft-branded release)
> - code-git AUR (in-development open-source version)

I think I may have had installed the wrong version at first (the non insiders one was the open source release: `code`.

Actually when playing with the official `tar.gz` from the website (which is the hard way equivalent of installing `visual-studio-code-bin`) it worked fine.

The right way is to (obviously) go with the official Microsoft branded release: `visual-studio-code-bin`.